# Facility to test cold weather gear in London UK

Tags: gear, cold-weather, uk

I'm debating what equipment to buy to prepare for a cold weather in mountain terrain and felt it might be useful to test what different temperatures feel like while wearing chosen equipment. My companion disagrees that some heavy duty items are required and we would both gain from finding out who is right, if only to settle the argument.

Rather than flying away to find colder climates, I vaguely recall seeing something about test facility which can simulate cold, wind and rain conditions on demand in a retail store in London. I never went in, so my imagination may be running wild, but I guess it was a some kind of giant fridge with fans and hoses to simulate wind and rain as well.

Unfortunaltey I don't recall which store had this set up and most importantly, what that kind of facility is called, which has made it hard to Google for. Any ideas?

Comment: Aside from just walking into a meat freezer, I've never heard of anything like what you're asking. But to be more clear, this is not something that people usually do when buying gear.

Comment: I think I have located one in Munich: http://www.retail-square.com/shops/globetrotter-0

Comment: this would be of limited use. Spending 10 minutes in a freezer does not simulate a cold and wet 10 hours on a Scottish Monroe. Your answer is layering. Take multiple layers and use this to moderate/maintain your temperature. Too cold, add layers, too warm remove layers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're thinking of the Vertical Chill, at Ellis Brigham in Covent Garden? 
This is like a giant refrigerator for ice climbing but not rain and wind.

http://www.vertical-chill.com/vertical-chill-london.htm

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the [Indoor Skiing Snow Centre](http://www.meribel-unplugged.co.uk/travel_articles_indoor_skiing_in_the_uk.htm) near London?

> The temperature in The Snow Centre ranges from -2 to -6 degree Celsius

Comment: It was not, but that's an option certainly.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Top Gear Winter Olympics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear_Winter_Olympics) special Richard Hammond (and the car he is inside) are subjected to extreme winter conditions (-40°) at the [MIRA test labs](http://www.mira.co.uk/our-services/climatic-wind-tunnels).  Hilarity ensues.

Top Gear segment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM46RoD3-yM